# Vulkan vkResetCommandPool vs vkResetCommandBuffer

Tags: graphics, vulkan

The description of `vkResetCommandPool` just says

> Resetting a command pool recycles all of the resources from all of the command buffers allocated from the command pool back to the command pool. All command buffers that have been allocated from the command pool are put in the initial state.

Is it the same as resetting all the existing command buffers allocated from the command pool, which is the same as calling `vkResetCommandBuffer` for each single buffer assuming that the command pool was created with `VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT`.

I am wondering whether the additional control brought by `VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT` will impact the performance. If I have a few swapchain images and want to reset my command buffer when drawing each frame. Is it better to create a separate command pool for each swapchain image and reset the corresponding command pool when drawing every frame, or just create a single command pool with `VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT` and reset the corresponding command buffer when drawing each frame?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is mostly going to be "it depends". How many command buffers do you have per frame?

If you have many command buffers per frame, it's probably less expensive to have one pool per frame and reset the pool.

If you have few command buffers per frame then it's probably cheaper to reset individual command buffers.

That said, it's entirely implementation-defined behaviour, so if you have a concern about it write a small benchmark and test your hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got the answer. For the first case it is reasonable as resetting the command pool batches the command buffer resetting operations together. For the second case I am just wondering whether resetting the command pool does anything else than resetting the individual command buffers.

Comment: Drivers do various memory pooling techniques to reduce memory management overheads, so resetting the pool may have different effects on how the driver recycles memory across command buffers. But YMMV - this is all implementation-internal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice to reset the pool in one go. Not only is it likely to give better performance, but it's simpler to manage. Few games manage the lifetime of individual command buffers, unless for ancilliary (secondary) command buffers.

When in doubt, enable the best practice check in your `vk_layer_settings.txt`:

```
khronos_validation.validate_best_practices = true
```